# problem integrating my own model .tflite on the tensorflow image classification application

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I created my own image classification model with Python, I used it in the Tensorflow image classification application; https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
My problem is that when I use the .tflite model generate from     teachable machine the application works and when I use my own model the application does not work.

that when I use the .tflite model from teachable machine de google the application works and when I use my own model the application does not work.